# Favorite question/Star button. What is it for?

Tags: support

I've looked through the FAQ  and about page and i can't seem to find any mention of the favorite/star button... Whats it for?

Thanks!

Comment: Starring is a great learning tool. SE API allows grabbing the list of favorites which is then converted into a neat not-so-little e-book...

Answer (score 5):

It is for you to star your favourite questions so you can find them easily at a later date.

If you go to your profile you will see favourites in between badges and bounties

[image]